# Login to site using idhttp

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I am trying to login to a website via delphi / indy. Currently all I have is a button (used to send a password / username) it calls this procedure.

```
procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
UserID :string;
Password :string;
res :TStringStream;
details :Tstringlist;
multiformupload: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
//create ini file to hold password / usesr name
        UserID:=name;
        Password:=pass;

        Res  := TStringStream.Create();
        MultiFormUpload := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;

        MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('user',UserID);
        MultiformUpload.AddFormField('pass',Password);
        idhttp1.Request.ContentType := '8bit';
        //idhttp1.Get('http://codeelf.com',res);
        idhttp1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid',Multiformupload,res);
        memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(res);

        res.Free;
end;
```

When I look at the site code, i have this.

```
 <form id="gridForm" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkLoginForm()">
      <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
         <tr>
            <td align="left" id="my_username">Username:</td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" id="user" name="user" maxlength="12" autocomplete="off" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" id="my_password">Password:</td>
            <td align="right"><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" maxlength="20" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
              &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
               <input id="submission" type="submit" class="button" name="sublogin" value="Login" /></td>
         </tr>
```

So the submission button value is just login. Thus i dont know where to POST the data. How can i find this out? And once i do find out the url, I should just be able to add it to the `idhttp1.Post` correct?

Comment: The browser will post the form data to the URI in the form action attribute. If it is not specified, the browser will post the form data to the URI of the document which contains the form.

Comment: @Mjn it seems to post to the document as i did find this. `document.getElementById('submission').click();`  But how do i call this from idhttp?  Is this a javascript? as i see no function called click on the page source

Comment: The form will not be "posted to the document". It will be sent to to the server, and the POST request will include the same URI where the HTML containing the form came from.

Comment: The click() is just the internal Javascript code which will simulate a click on the specified element. In this case it will simulate a click on the submit button of the the form.

Comment: Show how would i write the POST url to this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. you are not submitting everything that is in the login form.  You must do so.  That includes the value of the login button itself, since it has `name` and `id` values assigned.  Some servers require that button value.
2. you are setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` to an invalid value.  However, it happens that `TIdHTTP.Post(TIdMultipartFormDataStream)` ignores a user-provided `ContentType` and uses the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream.RequestContentType` property instead.  So this does not affect your login, but it is still a bug in your code.
3. you are ignoring the response's charset when loading the response data into the `TMemo`.  You should use the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that returns `String` and assign that to the `TMemo.Text` property.  Let `TIdHTTP` handle the charset decoding for you.
4. you are leaking the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` object.

Try this:

```
procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
  MultiFormUpload: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  MultiFormUpload := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('user', name);
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('pass', pass);
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('sublogin', 'Login');

    //IdHTTP1.Get('http://codeelf.com');
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid', MultiFormUpload);
  finally
    MultiFormUpload.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, some servers send cookies to the client when it requests the login page, and then those cookies need to be sent back as part of the login process.  If posting to the login URL by itself does not work, try retrieving the login page first, then post your login credentials, and let `TIdHTTP` handle the cookies for you:

```
procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
  MultiFormUpload: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  MultiFormUpload := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('user', name);
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('pass', pass);
    MultiFormUpload.AddFormField('sublogin', 'Login');

    IdHTTP1.Get('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid', TStream(nil));
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid', MultiFormUpload);
  finally
    MultiFormUpload.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Update**: there is another problem with your original code.  The HTML login form does not ask for a `multipart/form-data` post to begin with, so `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` is the wrong class to use.  Use a `TStringList` instead so `TIdHTTP.Post()` will send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post instead:

```
procedure TForm5.Login(name: string; Pass: string);
var
  Params: TStringList;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('user='+name);
    Params.Add('pass='+pass);
    Params.Add('sublogin=Login');

    //IdHTTP1.Get('http://codeelf.com');
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('http://codeelf.com/games/the-grid-2/grid', Params);
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: great news! this does seem to work, but i dont get anything in the memo, what i had expected is the page sourcecode.. but maybe that is wrong

Comment: `TIdHTTP.Post()` does return the response page content.  If it is coming back blank, then either there is no content to begin with, or there was a charset conversion error resulting in a blank string. If your original `Post()` code was returning non-blank data in your `TStringStream`, but my code is returning a blank `String`, then the latter is the culprit. The reason I avoid `TStringStream` is because it requires you to know the charset ahead of time, but you don't know what that is until the response is actually received. The `String` version of `Post()` uses the response charset to decode.

Comment: actually before it would freeeze up , this way it does not freeze up.  so this way is better.. i will try a few other things and see what i get.. Have you tried this? did you get anything in the memo?

Comment: ok so using wireshark, i can tell the get is ok, the post is giving me a 302 error, then directs me back to the login page. I think the blank data i get is from the 302, not from the redirect. As teh redirect is showing the data on the login. So I must be sending the data wrong? or at least the parmeters

Comment: another thing when i do a post via webbrowser it says `POST /games/the-grid-2/grid/ HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)` not `(text/html)` like i am posting with the app. Dont know if this matters.

Comment: Great Got it working, seems i had to do another GET after the post...?? still cant get the code to show up in the memo from the GET but I do know its logging me.

Comment: To send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post, you have to use a `TStrings` instead of a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`. I did not catch that in your original message. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The POST must go to the same URL where you retrieved the HTML page from as the action attribute is empty.

Depending on the server, a successful login will send cookies back to the client which need to be included with the next requests.

Wether cookies are used or not can be found out if you analyze the browser/client communication with Firebug or a HTTP proxy tool like Fiddler.

If the server uses proxies, you need to add cookie support to your client code. Indy supports HTTP cookies transparently (TIdCookieManager).

Comment: Ok let me see if this is correct?  I use post(site) save the cookie then post(site) again. I used wire shark and it does requre cookies, also found a paramater `user=someuser&pass=Somepass&sublogin=login`  Will i need to use this in the second post after i get the cookies?

Comment: @GlenMorse after a successful authentication (login), requests no longer have to include the credentials (user name / password). Normally, the cookies alone allow the server to associate all requests with the user.

Comment: @GlenMorse the Indy Cookie manager will save the cookie, and include it in the next requests as long as they use the same instance of TIdHTTP and its associated cookie manager. If you destroy and create new TIdHTTP instances between POSTs, the cookies will be lost.

Comment: On some servers, even requesting the login page sends cookies that are then sent back as part of the login. So if simply posting to the login URL does not work, try `Get()`'ing the login page first, then `Post()` to the login URL.